# i keep having [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core) #0 MethodChannel._invokeMethod package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:175 #1 MethodChannel.invokeListMethod package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:363 #2 MethodChannelFirebase._initializeCore package:firebase_core_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:31 #3 MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp package:firebase_core_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:73 #4 Firebase.initializeApp

Answer (score 0):

delete the application on your emulator (or wherever you work)

execute

> flutter clean

in your working directory and rebuild the app.
flutter sometimes does not recognize plugins automatically.

Comment: i still got the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and deleting app on device/simulator and installing it again helped me